# How does a JIT compiler compile a function that contains a call to another non-jitted function or virtual call

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, jit, vtable

I understand what JIT compilers do, it uses counters to detect hot codes and compiles them, and stores them in the code cache, so that next time the function won't need to be interpreted. But this brings me to two questions:

1. How does a JIT compiler compile a function that contains calls to other non-jitted functions. Calls to other non-jitted functions need to let the jitted function, which is the native code, calls the *outside* function that is still supposed to be executed through the interpreter of the JIT compiler.
2. The second one is a variant of the first one. How does a JIT compiler compile a function that contains a virtual call? it seems that it has to hard-code the vtable lookup procedure into the native code, but what will happen if the vtable is living in the virtual machine, then there must be a way to access the vtable *inside* the generated native code, but how could this be done, if the virtual machine is implemented using a language like C or C++ maybe you can hard-code the memory address of the vtable into the native code, but how can I do the same if the virtual machine is implemented in some managed language that its users are not encouraged to, or simply cannot access the address of an object, and even if I can access the address the object might be moved during the compact phase of the garbage collector.